# rails generate fixture for rspec unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails, fixtures

New to **Rspec** as unit testing. I manually create fixture named `account_holders.yml`. But apparently, it's not get loaded or saved so my rspec couldn't find it. What's the proper way to add fixture in rails?

Comment: I would suggest you to look into https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl and https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails